# MySql select islands and remove gaps in sequence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table below

```
Id | cont
----------
 1 |  0
 2 |  1
 3 |  0
 4 |  1
 5 |  2
 6 |  3
 7 |  0
 8 |  1
 9 |  2
10 |  0
11 |  1
12 |  2
13 |  3
14 |  4
```

I need to get islands which is sequence number from 2 and above, and remove the gaps.

The result should be

```
Id | cont
----------
 5 |  2
 6 |  3
12 |  2
13 |  3
14 |  4
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Why isn't Id 9 included in the result?

Comment: I'm using MySQL, but if there's an answer using ms sql server, it's ok as well.

Comment: @jarlh the island must be sequence number from 2 and above

Comment: Can we assume in each sequence every number is the previous plus one? I mean, can a sequence like 0,1,3,6 exists?

Comment: the sequence will always from 0, but it may stop at any number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the IDs will be monotonically increasing, you can achieve that in a few steps.

First of all, for each number you get the first preceding zero

```
select  t1.ID, t1.cont, max(t2.ID) max_id
from    yourTable t1
join    yourTable t2
on      t1.id >= t2.id
where   t2.cont = 0
group by t1.ID, t1.cont
```

Then use this to get the sequences with more than one row greater than 1

```
select  t1.max_id, count(*)
from    (
            select  t1.ID, t1.cont, max(t2.ID) max_id /* STEP 1 */
            from    yourTable t1
            join    yourTable t2
            on      t1.id >= t2.id
            where   t2.cont = 0
            group by t1.ID, t1.cont
        ) t1
where   cont > 1
group by t1.max_id
having count(*) > 1
```

And finally join these two to get the id and values you want

```
select  t1.id, t1.cont
from    (
            select  t1.ID, t1.cont, max(t2.ID) max_id /* STEP 1 */
            from    yourTable t1
            join    yourTable t2
            on      t1.id >= t2.id
            where   t2.cont = 0
            group by t1.ID, t1.cont

        ) t1
join    (
            select  t1.max_id, count(*) /* STEP 2 */
            from    (
                        select  t1.ID, t1.cont, max(t2.ID) max_id
                        from    yourTable t1
                        join    yourTable t2
                        on      t1.id >= t2.id
                        where   t2.cont = 0
                        group by t1.ID, t1.cont
                    ) t1
            where   cont > 1
            group by t1.max_id
            having count(*) > 1
        ) t2
on      t1.max_id = t2.max_id
where   t1.cont > 1
```

You can see this query in action **[here](http://rextester.com/RSUC89305)**

Comment: Sir.. sorry to interupt.. how about if the condition changes, so the result is the sequence of 0-1-2-and above. So the gaps are 0, 0-1 and 0-1-2

Comment: Changing  `where cont > 1` to   `where cont > 2` in the sixth row from bottom will be enough

Answer (score 1):

Or just..

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM my_table x 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON (y.id = x.id - 1 OR y.id = x.id + 1) 
            AND y.cont >= 2 
          WHERE x.cont >= 2;
```